# What spacecraft that fell to Earth spent a night in Jail?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Comments below [this question on Space.SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34513/12102) link to the article [Government report on 'space balls' released](http://www.stuff.co.nz/the-press/4542804/Government-report-on-space-balls-released).

Most of the article is about Kosmos 482 but the end mentions another spacecraft fuel tank that also was recovered.

> John Lindores found a space ball on his property on April 3. The ball is on permanent loan to the Ashburton Aviation Museum.
>
> "We thought it was an April Fool's joke to start with. The police came and took it away. It caused quite a stir at the time. They treated it with great care because they were afraid it was radioactive. They took it to Ashburton jail and locked it up for the night."

---

The story of the fallen space object spending a night in the local jail reminds me of some old movie. I thought it might be the original 1971 [*The Andromeda Strain*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066769/) film, but it seems that in that case the spacecraft landed in the middle of the town and people "were cut down in mid-stride" ([YouTube](https://youtu.be/YMbSpnlOOtE?t=59)).

Still, I remember something about a recovered spacecraft first being taken to a jail(?), perhaps in the back of a pickup truck, in an old (1950 to 1980) film that ultimately causes a big problem (harm to people). However, I just can't place it.

Comment: In the Andromeda Strain they take it to the local doctor's surgery, if memory serves

Comment: @Valorum yes, the crystallized blood, that's right! I'm still remembering a jail.

Comment: @Valorum was the spacecraft shown to be taken to the  local doctor's surgery by a pickup or farmer's truck from a field? I haven't seen the film since the 1970's. It made a huge impression on me but I'm still watching it from memory.

Comment: With some imagination, you may be looking for "Planet of the apes"? :)

Comment: @nicolallias the spacecraft was small, carried by one or two people, and the people were human, thanks!

Comment: In this trailer for the movie, you can see the probe sitting in the doctor's office at 0:17 seconds in. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFc08ijPtkc

Comment: @OrganicMarble there's https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3JE5.jpg (found [here](https://highdefdiscnews.com/2019/06/18/the-andromeda-strain-special-edition-blu-ray-review/)) and https://i.stack.imgur.com/04x9M.jpg (found [here](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066769/mediaviewer/rm2878197248)) and https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PY70.jpg (from [here](https://cinephiliabeyond.org/the-andromeda-strain/)). However I can't remember if the moving of the spacecraft from where it landed into the office, then opening it was shown explicitly in the film or not.

Comment: @OrganicMarble also here https://youtu.be/a52xsYImOUc?t=54 and https://youtu.be/8qEsqjJAY-k?t=61 Also I may be mixing this together with scenes from the beginning of [The Blob](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051418/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) as well https://youtu.be/2EB6TdpKdxk

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm now certain that that is what I was thinking of. Feel free to post it as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: @OrganicMarble just asked: [Did they torture and kill a monkey during the filming of Andromeda Strain?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/110281/45856)